# How to account for signal transmission in measurements of beat frequency between separated senders?

Tags: optics, frequency, interference, redshift

An important technique in optics experiments is the determination of the beat frequency (a.k.a. beat note) between (optical, as good as monochromatic, suitably stable) signals of two senders; say, of sender $\mathsf A$ sending with frequency $\nu_{\mathsf A}$, and of sender $\mathsf B$ sending with frequency $\nu_{\mathsf B}$.

Generally, the two senders may be far apart. Their signals are separately transmitted (e.g. by different optical fibers), they may be separately conditioned (e.g. to match their amplitudes and polarizations), then coupled and directed together to one receiver, $\mathsf R$ (such as a photo diode; cmp. https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07650 Fig. 1 (b), right side).

Under suitable conditions (of signal emission, transmission, conditioning and coupling) the joint intensity at the receiver varies distinctly at a (practically constant) comparatively small frequency, the beat frequency $f^{\text{beat}}_{\mathsf R \, \Leftarrow \, {}^{\mathsf A}_{\mathsf B}}$.

Further, for the purpose of my following question, let's distinguish (conceptually, and through correspondingly distinct notation) between

- the sending frequency $\nu_{\mathsf A}$ of sender $\mathsf A$ itself, and
- the reception frequency $\nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf A}$ of receiver $\mathsf R$ itself in response to receiving the signal transmitted from sender $\mathsf A$ (i.e. **only** the signal transmitted from sender $\mathsf A$, while transmission from sender $\mathsf B$ to receiver $\mathsf R$ is completely blocked, and any other noise be negligible).

If the frequencies $\nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf A}$ and $\nu_{\mathsf A}$ are not exactly equal then their (non-zero) difference

$$ \nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf A} \, - \, \nu_{\mathsf A} := \Delta^{\text{trans}}_{(\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf A)} $$

may be called "frequency shift, in transmission of sender $\mathsf A$'s signal to receiver $\mathsf R$".

Likewise, let's distinguish between

- the sending frequency $\nu_{\mathsf A}$ of sender $\mathsf B$ itself, and
- the reception frequency $\nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf B}$ of receiver $\mathsf R$ itself in response to receiving the signal transmitted from sender $\mathsf B$ (i.e. **only** the signal transmitted from sender $\mathsf B$, while transmission from sender $\mathsf A$ to receiver $\mathsf R$ is completely blocked, and any other noise be negligible).

If the frequencies $\nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf B}$ and $\nu_{\mathsf B}$ are not exactly equal then their (non-zero) difference

$$ \nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf B} \, - \, \nu_{\mathsf B} := \Delta^{\text{trans}}_{(\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf B)} $$

may be called "frequency shift, in transmission of sender $\mathsf B$'s signal to receiver $\mathsf R$".

**My question:**

**Is**
$\qquad f^{\text{beat}}_{\mathsf R \, \Leftarrow \, {}^{\mathsf A}_{\mathsf B}} = \mid  \, \nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf A} - \, \nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf B} \, \mid \qquad $
**exactly${}^{({\Large \ast})}$ ?**,

whereby with the definitions given above also $f^{\text{beat}}_{\mathsf R \, \Leftarrow \, {}^{\mathsf A}_{\mathsf B}} = \mid  \, (\nu_{\mathsf A} - \nu_{\mathsf B}) + (\Delta^{\text{trans}}_{(\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf A)} - \Delta^{\text{trans}}_{(\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf B)}) \, \mid$,

such that the beat frequency of receiver $\mathsf R$ explicitly depends on the frequencies $\nu_{\mathsf A}$ and $\nu_{\mathsf B}$ of the two senders $\mathsf A$ and $\mathsf B$ themselves **and also explicitly depends on** any frequency shifts, in transmission of sender $\mathsf A$'s signal to receiver $\mathsf R$, and/or in transmission of sender $\mathsf B$'s signal to receiver $\mathsf R$.

**Or is instead**
$\qquad f^{\text{beat}}_{\mathsf R \, \Leftarrow \, {}^{\mathsf A}_{\mathsf B}} = \mid  \, \nu_{\mathsf A} - \nu_{\mathsf B} \, \mid \qquad$
**exactly${}^{({\Large \ast})}$ ?**,
as is suggested e.g. on p. 10 of the article linked above,
i.e. regardless of any possible or imaginable frequency shifts, in transmission of sender $\mathsf A$'s signal to receiver $\mathsf R$, and/or in transmission of sender $\mathsf B$'s signal to receiver $\mathsf R$.

$(^{\Large \ast}$: Not to put too fine a point on it, and considering applications such as [this](https://sci-hub.st/10.1038/s41566-020-0619-8), take *"**exactly**"* as *"**within*** ${\mathbf{\pm 1~{\rm Hz}}}$".$)$

Comment: What kind of receiver are you using that produces a response at the optical frequency so that you could expect $\nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf A}\ne 0$?

Comment: @The Photon: _"What kind of receiver [...]"_ -- For all intends and practical purposes: The devive labelled "PD" in the center of Fig. 1 (b) right, showing the "SLAVE Clock: UTokyo", of https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07650 _"that produces a response at the optical frequency so that [...] $\nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf A} \ne 0$"_ -- Well: such a response, at this optical frequency, may be at **very** small intensity. Do you mean I should have considered "noise"? Could the "PD" perhaps be thought substituted or supplemented by a possibly more suitable "optical sensor"? ...

Comment: That photodetector in that setup only needs to output the beat frequency, not the optical frequency. The beat frequency is several orders of magnitude lower than the beat frequency. If it did output the optical frequency (~215 THz) it would be producing light, not an electrical signal, and no electrical waveguide would be able to transmit it. (Furthermore, if you have a 215 THz signal, and want to produce a 215 THz signal, why use any device at all? Just guide your existing 215 THz signal to wherever you want to use a 215 THz signal.)

Comment: @The Photon: _"[...] no electrical waveguide would be able to transmit it."_ -- Why not with a very, **very** small (but non-zero) transmission coefficient ?!? I appreciate your "practical mindset", but the point is: to give a definition, at least in principle, of the quantities $\nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf A}$ and $\nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf B}$; neither of which involves any outright requirements on amplitude or intensity (apart from that these should at least be thought of as non-zero). I edited my question, trying to clarify this.

Comment: You are right that the frequency that arrives at the detector is not the same as the one that left the transmitter. The linked paper talks about how, for example, subway trains running near the fiber can disturb the phase of the received signal (and thus they must also disturb its frequency by at least a small amount). But practically no photodetector available can measure the arriving optical frequency, except by mixing it with another nearly-equal-frequency signal to produce a much lower beat frequency.

Comment: @The Photon: _"But practically no photodetector available can measure the arriving optical frequency, except by [...]"_ -- So: this practicality does not impair my above definition of $\nu^{\text{rec}}_{\mathsf R \, \leftarrow \, \mathsf A}$ etc., does it? _"[...] the frequency that arrives at the detector"_ -- Informally speaking, fair enough, of course. But I hesitate to strictly attribute any particular frequency to [a photon surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_surface); preferring instead: "the frequency **of the detector** in response to ...".

Comment: @The Photon: _"The linked paper talks about how, for example, subway trains running near the fiber can disturb the phase of the received signal"_ -- Right. Some noisy-irregular "disturbance of the phase" is not quite a systematic-persistent "frequency shift". But consider [that paper](https://sci-hub.st/10.1038/s41566-020-0619-8) by pretty much the same authors, with pretty much the same expression for $f^{\text{beat}}$... (I didn't refer to that paper outright in my OP question only because it lacks a sketch with an explicit beat-"PD".)

Comment: @The Photon: _"You are right that the frequency that arrives at the detector is not the same as the one that left the transmitter."_ -- Excellent! Please consider expanding this assessment into a full answer.